# String comparison in a Bash script called from terminal or keyboard shortcut gives different output

Tags: string, bash, comparison

I have two monitors and I am calling a bash script to move the current window to the monitor above. Below there is a sample of my code (I changed the variable names to be more descriptive).

The problem is in the last if-statement `if [[ $currentWindowPosition == "above" ]]`. When I call the script from terminal and my window in the the monitor above I get:

```
currentWindowPosition=above!
The window will stay on this monitor
```

but when I call it from a keyboard shortcut (and redirect the output to a file) I get:

```
currentWindowPosition=above!
The current monitor is on the bottom
```

How come? I also tried different versions of that test but without success. Thank you in advance.

```
yOfCurrentWindow=$(xwininfo -id $(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}') | grep "Absolute upper-left Y:" | cut -d: -f2)
yResolutionOfmonitor1=$(xrandr | awk '/ connected/ { print $3 }' | sed -n '1 p' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="x"} { print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="+"} {print $1}')

if [ $yOfCurrentWindow -lt $yResolutionOfmonitor1 ] 
then currentWindowPosition="above"
else currentWindowPosition="below"
fi

echo "currentWindowPosition=$currentWindowPosition!"

if [[ $currentWindowPosition == "above" ]] 
then echo "The window will stay on this monitor"
else echo "The current monitor is on the bottom"
fi
```

Comment: How do you ensure that `$currentWindowPosition` has a value other than "above" if the test in the first `if` statement is false? (By the way, with bash you can use `if ((yOfCurrentWindow < yResolutionOfMonitor)); then` instead of the old-style test command (`[`) command.)

Comment: Please use double quotes in `if [[ "$currentWindowPosition" == "above" ]]`. Instead, the double quotes in `"above"` are not needed.

Comment: Extend the first IF-THEN clause: `if [ "$yOfCurrentWindow" -lt "$yResolutionOfmonitor1" ] 
then currentWindowPosition="above" 
else currentWindowPosition="below"
fi`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answers! My code is more complex than this, and I did not think it necessary to include the line:
else currentWindowPosition="below"
Now I did it because I see it causes confusion. 
I tried Jdamian's if [ "$currentWindowPosition" = below ] and it works! Notice the single equal sign. Could you explain what was happening here? $currWindowPosition already had the value "above", but if [ $currPos == "below" ] was false when called from keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jdamian's suggestion to use: 
if [ "$currentWindowPosition" = below ] 
works. Notice the single equal sign.